# iOS: custom segue and presentViewController not working as expected

Tags: ios, segue

I'm using a custom segue which looks like this:

@implementation ModalPushSegue

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *fromController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *toController = self.destinationViewController;
    UIView *fromView = fromController.view; 
    UIView *toView = toController.view; 

    CGPoint centerStage = toView.centerStage;
    toView.center = toView.rightStage;

    [fromView.window addSubview:toView];
    [fromController addChildViewController:toController];

    [UIView transitionWithView:toView 
                      duration:0.5 options:0
                    animations:^{
                        toView.center = centerStage;
                    }
                    completion:nil];

}
```

This works well in that the view is slide on from the right as expected and the controller is added to the controller hierarchy.

But later in the added controller I do this:

```
[self presentViewController:anotherController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I would expect this to slide the new controller's view up the screen ala modal style. But what happens instead is the the new view doesn't appear. And when I later remove this controller, it's view flashes up and slides off the screen, leaving a black background instead of the view that was originally there.

I've been playing around with this for a while and if I change the code to

```
//[self presentViewController:oauthController animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.view addSubview:oauthController.view];
[self addChildViewController:oauthController];
```

Then the view appears as expected, although not resized.

My problem appears to be with the way that the segues setup the hierarchy vs the way that `presentViewController` does things. I've done lots of reading and searching but so far have not been able to get a clear picture of exactly what is going on.

I've also played around with using `presentViewController` in the segue but instead of laying the new view over the old one, the screen goes black and the new view then slides on.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set a Storyboard ID on your destination view controller (in the storyboard), then try the following code:

```
AnotherController *viewC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnotherController"]; 
ModalPushSegue    *segue = [[ZHCustomSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"coolSegueName" source:self destination:viewC];

[segue perform];
```